# Thin vertical scrollbars such as those in the Steam client are a usability nightmare. Why do designers still use them?

Tags: scrolling

As an example I detest using the Steam client on a PC and have realized one of the biggest reasons is that scrolling the commonly very 'tall' pages is utterly painful.

Scrolling by clicking and dragging the scroll thumb bar is by far the fastest and most efficient way to scroll tall pages. For example I can easily jump to say 3/4 of the way down the page.  Keys just can't do this as well (also force me to go to the keyboard in a heavily mouse driven UI) and let's not even waste a second thinking about the scroll wheel.

These vertical scrollbars are pixels wide and these scrollbars are not configurable in any way.  At least if I am in the browser version I use an addon that lets me override the site scrollbars.  Sadly the browser version of steam is missing a lot of client functionality so dumping the client isn't an option.

Even worse is that if I want to quickly move the mouse to the vertical scrollbar, I cannot rely on Fitt's law and move the mouse quickly to the screen edge and just scroll.  Instead I have to painstakingly move the pointer left a couple of pixels until over the scrollbar.  This is just infuriating!

Yes, I have raised this months ago in the dumping ground that is the Steam discussion forum.  I received no response apart from some passerby who could only mention the half-baked custom CSS option that is wiped whenever steam updates (often daily).

Comment: Hi @Ash, the answers to this question could be subjective. Could you provide some screenshots and reframe the question to receive more focused answers for e.g. - what could be a better alternative for this? Examples of platforms that do this better? What is the best usability practice etc.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to find out? Have you done any research yourself that you can share? Because now it sounds more like a rant than that you are really interested in finding an answer.

Comment: The question here should probably be 'how wide should scrollbars be?'

Comment: Please provide gif-s